# Dividing a polygon in desired way

Tags: geometry

I have a bunch of polygons. I want to divide them with a line that will pass through the center and divide the polygon into two equal pieces with respect to area. 
I cannot seem to find a place to start with.

Hopefully clearer explanation of the problem:

What i have is a bunch of polygons in 3D. Like below. They are more or less flat polygons suspended in 3 dimensions. 
I have Cartesian coordinates of each of their vertices. Now what i want is to divide them into two equal pieces. The line can be in any direction and has to pass by the center of the polygon while dividing it into two equal pieces, areawise.

[image]
[image]

As an example above polygon with blue outline, if is divided as i want, would look something like this

[image]

With dividing (black) line passing through the center (in red) and dividing the polygon in two equal halves in terms of area.

About how the polygons are shaped.
1. Each of the polygon is flat or the vertices of each polygon is co-planar.
2. However, different polygons are on different plane, think of these polygons as tiles tilling a surface
3. The area is calculated for each polygon based on the its vertices that all lie on the same plane.
You can see these properties of the polygons on the following shape.
For the division, each polygon is to be divided with separate lines. The dividing line are not the same
[image]

Comment: Can you explain more on exactly what you're looking for? It's difficult to understand how to answer based on your current post. Are you looking for a *curve* that divides *all* of these polygons? Or a line that divides this *hoop* of polygons? Also some specifics on how this figure and the polygons it's made of are *defined* would be needed, as the picture is imprecise.

Comment: @WB-man hey i have tried to explain the question better. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: 1. It is still unclear if you are trying to divide *all* the polygons using a single line, or you are trying to divide each polygon separately using a different line per polygon.

2. all of the polygon vertices are coplanar? If not, how do you define the area of the polygons?

Comment: Okay i will further edit the problem addressing y our questions :) sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: The area of a "more or less flat" polygon is not defined.

Comment: Any plane through the centroid of the surface (assuming uniform surface density) will split thepolygons evenly.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, your phrasing of the problem is not quite precise.
There has been considerable work on computing the "center of area" of a
*single* convex polygon (a point $x$ such that any line through $x$ bisects the area), including this:

> Braß, Peter, Laura Heinrich-Litan, and Pat Morin. "Computing the center of area of a convex polygon." *International Journal of Computational Geometry & Applications* 13.05 (2003): 439-445.
>   [Journal link](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S021819590300127X?journalCode=ijcga).

They improved on my earlier work with a (then) student:

> Diaz, Matthew, and Joseph O'Rourke. "Algorithms for computing the center of area of a convex polygon." *The Visual Computer* 10.8 (1994): 432-442.

---

[image: Fig2]


<sup>Diaz-O'Rourke Fig.2: 5% contours.
The innermost contour ranges over $[45,46)$ percent.</sup>

---